# Terraform - Invalid index error with multiple count

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to configure 2 Public IP address, with 2 Network interface. What I have written so far is :

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                    = "test-pip${count.index}"
  count = 2
  location                = "${azurerm_resource_group.rc.location}"
  resource_group_name     = "${azurerm_resource_group.rc.name}"
  allocation_method       = "Dynamic"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 30
}
output "public_ip_address" {
  value = "${azurerm_public_ip.example.*.id}"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "test${count.index}"
  count = 2
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.rc.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rc.name}"

    ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1${count.index}"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.internal.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.example[count.index].id}"
  }
}
```

Later I will use these two IP, and NI to assign them to 2 VM machines.

When I run `terraform plan` , I get an error saying :

[image]

Terraform version  is `"v0.12.3"` and azure provider version is `"v1.40.0"`

Comment: Any more updates? Do you solve the problem with the answer? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think there is nothing wrong in the Terraform code that you provided in the question and all things work fine on my side.

The error also said:

```
The given key does not identity an element this collection value.
```

It probably because that your public IPs do not created before the network interface. It's strange. Terraform will sequence all the resources in the right sequence. Maybe you can try to upgrade the Terraform version. What I used is the newest version:

```
Terraform v0.12.19
+ provider.azurerm v1.41.0
```

Or you can try to change the code like this:

```
public_ip_address_id    = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.example.*.id, count.index)}"
```

Comment: The error was misleading, and you are right, everything magically worked once I upgraded the terraform version from "v0.12.3" to "v0.12.19" which is the latest stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is Terraform 0.12 and not Terraform 0.11 as the question syntax implies, the actual error is in the specific exported attribute. To access the ip address exported by the `azurerm_public_ip.example` resource, we would need to use the `ip_address` exported attribute and not the `id`. This is why the error is being thrown for an invalid key, although the specific reference in the error is indeed misleading.

We can update your code to fix this by:

```
ip_configuration {
  name                          = "testconfiguration1${count.index}"
  subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.internal.id}"
  private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.example[count.index].ip_address}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have changed the "public_ip_address_id" value to what you have suggested, and I am getting the exact same error. I am running terraform version "v0.12.3" and my azure provider version is "v1.40.0"

Comment: @Benjamin Ok if you are using 0.12, then that specific syntax you are using is valid for accessing the exported attribute, but you should know you are generally using 0.11 syntax and probably want to update.

Comment: @Benjamin Updated answer to reflect issue given this is 0.12 and not 0.11.

Comment: This seems like a known issue according to this git issue page. The solution that is offered in that conversation provides the "Public_IP_Address" as an input variable, however, in my case, I am generating the IP_Addresses using terraform. So I don't know how to adopt that solution into my issue. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/233?fbclid=IwAR3WSZMOcW_UhOYNElOFxGvbIV4uDXzVmlUiX3YrCEPF-U-XF0JI2uy7aac

Comment: @Benjamin Does updating to the latest Terraform 0.12 help?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change the code like this,It works for me:

`public_ip_address_id    = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.example.*.id, count.index)}"`